# Blank space between main div and footer

Tags: html, css, footer

There's a space between main div and footer, and I can not understand where it come from and how can I adjust it, I want it to be a footer down page, out of the main div.

```css
#main {
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}

#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 190px;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  /* Height of the footer */
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  /* Height of the footer */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: rgb(62, 45, 212);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="footer">--------Footer--------</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to clarify what your exact question is as it's hard to understand, but the spacing is coming from `top: 190px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container doesn't need to be positioned while it's child is absolutely positioned. If you want to keep a little bit of space between main and the container you could include a margin on the container. That way, whenever main gains changes in height, the footer will always keep the same space.

```css
#main {
  border: solid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}

#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  /* top: 190px; */
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  /* Height of the footer */
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  /* Height of the footer */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: rgb(62, 45, 212);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="footer">--------Footer--------</div>
</div>
```

Comment: top: 190px; this one should place the footer in the first screen (before main gains changes in height). Eventually i need the footer to be down page, and when the main gains hight, the footer scrool down without hide main content. Thaks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Remove `top: 190px;` from `#container`. It should work.

Comment: and also remove width: 100% from #main

Answer (score 0):

some tags have a default margin, you should use this line to clear them:

```
[tag]{
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  padding: 10px;
```

take that off and you get a space between main div and footer, but the footer stays visible in the end of your page.
If you really dont want any space or want to control it change in the container

```
  top: 190px;
```

You can also put the footer out of the container, that way you can control them independent.